# How to use a regular expression (glob) to search a file tree

Tags: regex, search, tree, glob

How do I adapt a search tree to handle limited regular expressions?

Given a file name, I need to find all nodes matching that file name. Nodes may contain usual file name globs (* and ?). Since this is a search tree, speed is of the essence.

I should add that the most important case for speed is the average time to rule out a match. In most cases matching will fail.

If the tree contained the following nodes:

```
foo, bar, foo*, *bar, foo?bar
```

- Searching for "foo" would return nodes 1 and 3.
- Searching for "bar" would return nodes 2 and 4.
- Searching for "fob" would return no nodes.
- Searching for "fooxbar" would return node 5.
- Searching for "foobar" would return nodes 3 and 4.

Comment: Is this a reverse problem (of regex): matching if a string belongs to a Regular Language or not?

Comment: Can you give us a sample i/o?

Comment: An example: Say the tree contained the following nodes:
foo, bar, foo*, *bar, foo?bar
Given any string (e.g. foo, foobar, fooxbar, fob, etc.), quickly find the node(s), if any, that match that string.

Comment: You should add the example to the question, not the comment.  Also, making it as clear as possible will help answerers.

Comment: I have used a few implementations to do this, based on AC and DFA and NFAs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho-Corasick_algorithm) search tree would fit the bill. "[Tries](http://jeffreystedfast.blogspot.com/2008/12/fun-with-tries.html)" is a very good article about this sort of thing and the [Etrie](http://svn.gnome.org/viewvc/evolution-data-server/trunk/libedataserver/e-trie.c?revision=9011&view=markup) implementation used in Evolution to replace regex searching.

To do the whole string matching, you can add beginning and ending anchor states. If scanning multi-line data, you could add the newline to the begin and end. You could also remove the part where it adds the cross linking for the partial matching starting a different match. This also allows faster exclusion.

Another algorithm for checking for membership in a string set is [CritBit](http://github.com/agl/critbit). This doesn't have Regex, but it is simple and tests complete strings.

Comment: That looks very promising, although I want to match the whole input string, not substrings within it. I'll read the links and confirm it fits the bill.

Comment: You can add a new front of line anchor, or if scanning multi line haystacks and add the line ending to the front of the needle. eg "\nsearch string".